# Combining Jquery filter with selector

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use a selector to filter on  all input type.

`var allInputTextboxes = $('input[type=text]');

 var filteredList = allInputTextboxes.filter('Id$=' + endWithId);`

I am not getting any result back. Is this doable?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `filter` selector is wrong.

You're probably trying to write `.filter('[id$="' + endWithId + '"]')`

However, you should use a classname instead.

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
var filteredList = allInputTextboxes.filter('Id$=' + endWithId);
```

to

```
var filteredList = allInputTextboxes.filter('[id$="' + endWithId+'"]');
```

(assuming you have id attribute)

because first one makes no sense